# Qt tooltip with arrow

Tags: c++, qt, tooltip, qt5

I have Qt 5.2.1 widgets-based project. I want to show cool tooltip with arrow while user hovers some labels (or any other widgets that can show image), like this:

[image: qtooltip with arrow]

But i found no examples for this. So am i able to do this with `QToolTip`? Or should i use another widgets to reach same look instead?

It is no matter what classes and styles i have to use, i need to reach similar effect any way.

I've tried to customize `QToolTip` with basic CSS but had failed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `QBalloonTip` which is an internal class defined in

```
QtDir/5.2.1/Src/qtbase/src/widgets/util/qsystemtrayicon_p.h
```

`QBalloonTip` inherits `QWidget` and it is implemented in `qsystemtrayicon.cpp` at the same directory. It has the following method to show a balloon tip:

```
void QBalloonTip::balloon(const QPoint& pos, int msecs, bool showArrow)
```

You can modify the source code of this class to have your desired balloon tip.

Comment: That is really dirty and deep trick! I've rewrote some parts of this class and everything works as expected, thank you very very much!

Comment: I don't understand why Qt developers didn't introduce this class as available for using, because IMHO this one is very helpful and many developers around world would prefer to use it instead classic QToolTip.